# Remove zero from unnumbered chapters' header

Tags: header-footer

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment}
\chaptermark{Acknowledgment}
\lipsum
\chapter*{Prolog}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prolog}
\chaptermark{Prolog}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

My question: How to remove '0.' from '0. ACKNOWLEDGMENT' and '0. PROLOG' in the unnumbered chapters' header?

Comment: Why don't you use `\frontmatter` for Preface etc. and `\mainmatter` for the introduction. Takes care of the page numbering as well. And you can use `\chapter` (no asterisk) and it will be in the toc as well. Double, triple deal.

Comment: There was never any feedback, was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\frontmatter`  and `\mainmatter` instead of doing stuff by hand.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{Acknowledgment}
\lipsum
\chapter{Prolog}
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```